# How to clear sorting and how to get visible columns only in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How to clear sorting by keeping button externally

and how to get visible columns only in jqgrid.

I used `$('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel')` where it showing hidden columns also. I dont want to display hidden columns.

is it possible to get only visible columns in jqgrid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am able to get visible columns in jqgrid as follows:

```
var columnModels = $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel');
for (var columnModelIndex in columnModels) {
    var columnModel = columnModels[columnModelIndex];
    if (! columnModel.hidden) {
            alert(columnModel.name);
    }
}
```

But I couldnt able to get how to reset sorting in jgGrid. can any one help